# Выполнение программы на java в чётких временных рамках

Tags: java

Пишу программу проверки рабочего состояния сервера. 
Через ssh подключаюсь к серверу и выполняю команду "uptime", результат сохраняю.

Может возникнуть ситуация, при которой сервер подвисает в непонятном состоянии и подключение к нему висит. 
Как сделать, чтобы код проверки сервера выполнялся в заданные временные рамки, к примеру, минут 5, не уложился, всё проверку не прошёл?

Единственное, что приходит в голову запускать два потока, один будет выполнять код, другой засыпать на конкретное время, по пробуждении проверять работает ли код и если работает, то убивать его, как то так

Comment: Многие синхронные операции имеют возможность передать таймаут. Приведите ваш код.

Comment: Да код, буквально две строки: SshHandler sshHandler = new SshHandler(user, psw, server.getAdres()); String uptime = sshHandler.executeCommands("uptime"); Сам SshHandler базируется на jsch. Ставить в нём таймоут, нет смысла, потому что когда сервер повиснит, даже putty повисает

Comment: @AlexMandelbrot у jsch [есть таймаут](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Session.html#connect-int-) и он работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть множество способов ограничить время выполнения метода. Google выдаёт 13 000 000 результатов на запрос "java limit execution time". Самый простой:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

    Future<?> future = executor.submit(() -> {
        // Код, который может повиснуть
    });

    executor.shutdown();    // Отклонять новые задачи

    try {
        future.get(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);  // Ожидать 5 минут
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {    // Задача была прервана
        System.out.println("job was interrupted");
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        System.out.println("caught exception: " + e.getCause());
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        future.cancel(true);              // Отменяем задачу
        System.out.println("timeout");
    }

    // Ожидаем завершения обработки задачей команды отмены
    if(!executor.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)){
        // Принудительно завершаем работу
        executor.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

[Отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20500382/1911548)

В Google Guava даже есть [класс делающий то же самое](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/).